# Matlab crashes with message: Killed. Try-catch doesn't work

Tags: matlab, crash

I'm executing a matlab function like this

```
try
    my_function(A)
catch
    disp('Error')
end
```

The code inside `my_function()` runs until it reaches this line.

```
rhs = -fda(:,known_list)*A(known_list);
```

With

```
size(known_list)  =  476862464   1
class(known_list) = 'double'

size(fda)         = 476862464    476862464
class(fda)        = 'double'

size(A)           = 476862464    1
class(A)          = 'double'
```

**Problem 1:** how do I solve the crash?

**Problem 2:** why does the try-catch statement not work and doesn't prevent the crash?

Comment: This is something you need to involve MathWorks customer support with. It looks like you found a bug. I don’t see how anyone here could help you with that.

Comment: Can you run it on mock-up datasets with ~1/100,000 the dimension? The amount of memory being used right now (2EB) makes no sense, but that should lead to an error, not a crash.